# Writing Python lists into file, items seperated by semicolon

Tags: python

```
source= numpy.array([8,9])
sink= numpy.array([7,8])
pop_percentage= numpy.array([50,70,85])
buses= numpy.array([100,150,200])
bus_capacity= numpy.array([60,90])
a=[source,sink,pop_percentage,bus_capacity,buses,['mat1','mat2']]
file = open("/home/deep/Desktop/DATA/First_Data_File.txt", "w")
for list in itertools.product(*a):
    for line in list:
        print>>file,list[0],list[1],list[2]
```

I have written the above code and I got the following format in file:

> 8 7 50

I need to separate the items using semicolon which should look like:

> 8;7;50

Please suggest the most pythonic way to get this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include semicolons in your print statement?

Comment: It's also a bit weird that you loop of the list, but don't use the line item

Comment: `file.write(';'.join(list) + '\n')`

Comment: Have you considered using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I prefer using [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to format my strings exactly the way I want them:

```
format_string = "{};{};{}"
print(format_string.format(list[0], list[1], list[2]))
```

It also appears that you're writing to the file using the print command?  I would suggest using [`file.write`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) instead:

```
with open('file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(format_string.format(list[0], list[1], list[2]))
```

---

<sub>The use of the `with` command ensures proper file handling thus removing the need for a `file.close()`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

```
print>>file, ";".join([str (l) for l in list[:3]])
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `str()` on list items before passing it to `str.join`. Also your square brackets are not balanced.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the print function from python3 :

If using Python 3.x :

```
print(*list, sep=';', file=fd)
```

If using Python 2.x (works at least for 2.7)

```
from __future__ import print_function
...
print(*list, sep=';', file=fd)
```

Beware : as soon as you use `from __future__ import print_function`, `print` becomes the Python3 function for the whole script file ...